# Informix Server 10 and remove CR character in select

Tags: sql, informix, chr

I need to remove the CR character in a select in Informix Server 10.

The function `chr` doesn't exist in version 10, so when I try a replace like that

```
REPLACE(text_column, chr(10), ' ')
```

I get an error like that:

> Routine (chr) can not be resolved. [SQL State=IX000, DB
>   Errorcode=-674]

The function `ascii(10)` doesn't work either.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to an **IDS 10** but see if this works out for you.

Bear in mind that this is an example for `LF`:

> `LF` - **ASCII** Code 10, Line Feed;
>
> `CR` - **ASCII** Code 13, Carriage Return.

First be sure your session has [IFX_ALLOW_NEWLINE](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1570.htm) set to true:

```
> EXECUTE PROCEDURE IFX_ALLOW_NEWLINE('T');

Routine executed.

>
```

Now let's see an example:

```
> CREATE TABLE tab1 (col1 CHAR(100));

Table created.

> INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES ('teste' || CHR(10) || '1');

1 row(s) inserted.

> SELECT col1 FROM tab1;



col1  teste
      1

1 row(s) retrieved.

> SELECT REPLACE(col1, '
> ', ' ') FROM tab1;



(expression)  teste 1

1 row(s) retrieved.

>
```

Side note:

- the [CHR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1952.htm?lang=en) function takes a a whole number in the range 0 through
  255 and returns the corresponding single-byte **ASCII** code point.
- the [ASCII](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1555.htm?lang=en) function takes a single argument of any character data type and returns the corresponding **ASCII** decimal code of the
  first character in the argument.

Answer (score 4):

This is the code I used, originally back in 2005, before Informix acquired the CHR and ASCII functions:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ascii(C CHAR) RETURNING INT AS result;
    DEFINE i INTEGER;
    IF c IS NULL THEN
        LET i = 0;
    ELSE
        SELECT val INTO i FROM ascii WHERE chr = c;
    END IF;
    RETURN i;
END PROCEDURE;

CREATE PROCEDURE chr(i INTEGER) RETURNING CHAR(1) AS result;
    DEFINE c CHAR;
    IF i < 0 OR i > 255 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION -746, 0, 'CHR(): integer value out of range 0..255';
    END IF;
    IF i = 0 OR i IS NULL THEN
        LET c = NULL;
    ELSE
        SELECT chr INTO c FROM ascii WHERE val = i;
    END IF;
    RETURN c;
END PROCEDURE;

CREATE TABLE ascii
(
    val     INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE CONSTRAINT u1_ascii,
    chr     CHAR(1) NOT NULL UNIQUE CONSTRAINT u2_ascii
);
REVOKE ALL ON ascii FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT SELECT ON ascii TO PUBLIC;
```

There's also a data file with numbers 1..255 and the corresponding character code.  It doesn't print well on a UTF-8 terminal since half the characters (from 128..255) are broken UTF-8 when treated as UTF-8.  It only works for code sets like ISO 8859-15 (8859-1, …).  You could decide that ASCII really means code points 1..127; that can be made to work since the UTF-8 and ASCII representations of those code points are identical.

If you really can't generate an appropriate load file for the ASCII table, let me know (by email — see my profile; it might already be available in the [IIUG Software archive](http://www.iiiug.org/software/)) and I can send you the gzipped archive with the data as well as the SQL above (a grand total of 1716 bytes in gzipped tar file format).